# Does canceling a user subscription through merchant console/API refunds him money?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, google-checkout, android-pay

According to In-App billing documentation, if users cancel's subscription by himself, his only way to receive a refund is by contacting a seller directly. But what happens if owner of the application cancels subscription through merchant account or through API call? Will user get a refund in this case? It looks like he will, but Google payment processing is not sure about this. When I cancel a user's subscription he receives email that explicitly states that "*No refunds will be issued*". But in user's Google wallet account it also states that "*Companyname has cancelled your order. You have been refunded in full.*".

Can someone confirm what actually happens? Is it possible that google uses same notification email for when user cancels subscription by himself and for when developer cancel's subscription for a user?

And the main question - **is it possible to cancel a subscription for user without a refund**? I'm planing to use some special offers for subscriptions, from time to time (reduced price, etc), and I'm actually would like for my users to pay less, and currently the only way to do it is cancel their subscription manually and make them purchase another subscription with reduced price (unfortunately it's not possible to change a subscription price as for now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So, It's not possible to cancel a subscription from merchant console - you can only cancel\refund individual transaction. Also, if you refund a customer he will receive a message that his subscription will continue (true) and no refunds will be issued (false). And you cant even send a custom messages.

So, canceling a subscription is ONLY possible through API call.

Answer (score 1):

Canceling a subscription will only prevent the recurrences from occurring and enable you to refund the initial order price.

You can partially refund or fully refund each recurrence if you wish to reduce the fee.

Comment: Actually, no. Canceling a subscription for user will prevent the recurrences, yes, but this will also refund user. Apparently, there is no way of canceling a subscription without refunding. But you can refund without canceling, yes.